# Python usage of commas

Tags: python

In a forum I have found this nice function (done by Pixie) converting from Roman to Arabic numbers.

```
def decoder(r):
    k=r
    if r=="":return "Don't leave the input blank"
    roman,s= {"M":1000,"CM":900, "D":500, "CD":400, "C":100, "XC":90, "L":50, "XL":40, "X":10, "IX":9, "V":5, "IV":4, "I":1},0
    while r!="":
        if r[:2] in roman:a,r=r[:2],r[2:]
        elif r[0] in roman:a,r=r[0],r[1:]
        else: return "Enter proper Decimal/Roman number as input"
        s+=roman[a]
    return s if encoder(int(s))==k else "Not a valid Roman Numeral"


a="MCM"
print(decoder (a.upper))
```

I am a super newbie of Python, and I do not understand the statement

if `r[:2]` in roman:`a,r=r[:2],r[2:]`

I know `r[:2]` and others are string slicing. What I do not understand is the usage of the commas: 
`a,r=r[:2],r[2:]` looks as a tuple but why? Is it an assignment?

Comment: Please format your code by indenting it by 4 spaces. You can also highlight it and press ctrl+k when in the editor.

Comment: And that appears to be destructuring syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Python has the ability to assign to multiple values on the sample line...

In this case, I am also moving the assignment lines to a new, indented line under the `if` and `elif` statements.

```
if r[:2] in roman:
    a,r = r[:2], r[2:]

elif r[0] in roman:
    a,r = r[0], r[1:]
```

The first assignment line is the same as:

```
a = r[:2]
r = r[2:]
```

The second one is the same as:

```
a = r[0]
r = r[1:]
```

Comment: Maybe in this case it happens to have the same effect.  However, `a,b=b,a` is not the same as `a=b` followed by `b=a`

Comment: @tonypdmtr the code shown by the OP does not do what you are suggesting... 
for sake of argument, we could generalize `r[:2]` to be `x` and `r[2:]` to be `y` and thus `a, r = x, y` would be equivalent to `a = x` and `r = y` NOT the variable swapping exercise you suggest.